# What NBA rules cover Draymond Green's free throw settling on the rim?

Tags: basketball, nba

In the Golden State vs Dallas game on May 24, 2022 Draymond Green shot a free throw which settled on the back of the rim and never dropped off.  What did the referees decide, and what NBA rules cover this?

Answer (score 1):

The free throw was counted as a miss.

Per the [NBA Rules](https://official.nba.com/rule-no-5-scoring-and-timing/), rule 5, Section 1(a):

> A legal field goal or free throw attempt shall be scored when a ball from the playing area enters the basket from above and remains in or passes through the net.

Since the ball did not pass through the net nor did it remain in the net, it was not a successful free throw attempt.